# Getting data from two model tables using sequelize

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sequelize.js

I am trying to add data from two tables using sequelize but only one table's data is returned. The table names are boilerHouse & compressorHouse.

Here is the route:

//(1)getting all Boiler House information

```
router.get("/alldataa", (req, res) => 

   Promise.all([boilerHouse.findAll(), compressorHouse.findAll()])
   .then((data) => {
    res.render('gigs', {
    gigs:data[0],
    gigs:data[1],

   //data[0] is response from tableA find
   // data[1] is from tableB
    })   

    })
   .catch(err => console.log(err)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here **issue** is **same name of json key** :

```
{
    gigs:data[0], // <----- gigs
    gigs:data[1]  // <----- gigs
}
```

If you use same name key then it **will get override by the last one**.

---

The solution to this is to use the **different key name** or merge 2 results into one

```
{
    gigs:data[0],
    gigs2:data[1]  // <----- Change this key name gigs2
}

// OR

{
     gigs: [ ...data[0] , ...data[1] ] // <--- Merge result into one
}
```

Comment: Thank you @VivekDoshi... this works perfectly {
     gigs: [ ...data[0] , ...data[1] ] // <--- Merge result into one
}